# Is it possible to read File from same folder where Azure function exists

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

In my Azure C# function I need to read a .txt file. I make the .txt file in Visual studio and set it to "copy Always".

Now I am using this code to read the file

```
var dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, "twinkle.txt");
```

this code doesn't work. When I open the folder which is the value of dir. It lead me to this directory ""C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.9""

How I can store a simple txt file in Azure function. Or I need Azure Storage for this.

Anything else I can do to get this done.

Update for showing file copied

[image]

Comment: Embed that file as a resource into assembly.

Comment: @tchelidze I am checking that way, thanks for idea.

Comment: @tchelidze yes, it's working. thanks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here is how to get to the correct folder:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, ExecutionContext context)
{
    var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, "twinkle.txt");
    // ...
}
```

This gets you to the folder with `function.json` file. If you need to get to `bin` folder, you probably need to go 1 level up, and then append `bin`:

```
// One level up
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, $"..{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}twinkle.txt"))

// Bin folder
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, $"..{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}bin{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}twinkle.txt"))
```

Comment: I don't believe I have access to `ExecutionContext` at startup.  Any other way to do that?

Comment: I had the same problem @BillNoel, I've posted an answer below that address the issue.

Comment: You can just add `ExecutionContext context` as a parameter to the Run method of your function.

Comment: `context.FunctionAppDirectory` gives you access to anything in the applications root folder `context.FunctionDirectory` only gives you access to the function specific directory

Comment: This will only work on Windows (if it works)

Comment: context.FunctionAppDirectory is the right answer now. Adding this in the event somebody else lands here and gets confused.

Answer (score 36):

For those like me who doesn't have access to `ExecutionContext` since we have to read a file in `Startup`.

```cs
var binDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var rootDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(binDirectory, ".."));

///then you can read the file as you would expect yew!
File.ReadAllText(rootDirectory + "/path/to/file.ext");
```

Also worth noting that `Environment.CurrentDirectory` might work on a local environment, but will not work when deployed to Azure.

Works inside functions too.

[Reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/issues/17#issuecomment-498596856)

Comment: Super useful for including Google.json files that are necessary for FirebaseAdmin functions!  Thanks, louie!

Comment: Wondering how this has worked for everyone. The executing assembly directory that I see is a temporary ASP.NET location and the config file of course does not exists there. "D:\local\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\80e1a0b8\1c033853\assembly\dl3\dc0956b6\".

Comment: Hmmm, that is strange indeed, it's maybe worth checking out the reference I included in the answer @PrasadKorhale

Comment: If I have the file in folder it doesn't work, it had to be directly places under root folder

Comment: @PrasadKorhale, because I think you are deploying the source code (as opposed to a built assembly) and your project is being compiled on the hosting of Functions App.

Comment: @lolelo then you have to navigate to the folder after getting the root directory similar to what I have in the answer `rootDirectory + "/your/sub/folders/file.ext"`

Comment: Needed to add "wwwroot" to the end for working.   var rootDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(binDirectory, ".."),"wwwroot"));

Answer (score 0):

To use a file called `pub_key.pem` in an Azure Function. I'd rather do this in the `.csproj` file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="pub_key.pem">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

and then read the file using a `Stream`

```cs
var assy = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AnyClassInFunction)); 
Stream fileStream = assy.GetManifestResourceStream(typeof(AnyClassInFunction),"pub_key.pem");
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a useful link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function

There is the possibility of a hard coded way:

```
File.ReadAllText("d:\home\site\wwwroot\NameOfYourFunction" + "/path/to/file.ext");
```

Comment: This sound cool but hard coded code are bad. What if Azure suddenly storing Function somewhere else ?