# ExecutionContext is null to non-function methods via IoC, alternative to ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory

Tags: azure, azure-functions

ExecutionContext is available to functon parameters.

However, it is not available to other methods via dependency inject, including Functions' constructor, like below:

```
    public class FunctionClass
    {   

        IOtherClass _otherclass;
       public FunctionClass(ExecutionContext  context,  //excetpion
                          IOtherClass otherclass)  //excetpion
       {
                 _otherclass = IOtherClass otherclass
       }

     [FunctionName("Car")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest req, ExecutionContext  context)
        {     
          }
    }

     public class OtherClass:IOtherClass
    {   
       public OtherClass(ExecutionContext  context)  //excetpion
       {}
    }
```

I need access to `ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory`, but don't want to pass ExecutionContext around, because want to use IoC instead.

Is there an alternative way to get the value of `ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory`?

VS 2017

Azure Functons 2.x

Comment: `ExecutionContext` is only available in the scope of a request. It wont be available as yet in the constructor for injection when the function class is initialized..

Comment: Is there another way to get the result of ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory?

Comment: Depends on where you want to access it from. If accessed from the function method then it will be available in the context.

Comment: Where else is it available?

Comment: What about within the ctor of OtherClass in OP?

Comment: You'll end up with the same problem. When these classes are initialized for injection the context has not been created as yet so it is not able to be injected,

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ExecutionContextOptions` to get application folder:

```
public class FunctionClass
  private ExecutionContextOptions context;

  public FunctionClass(IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions> executionContext) {
    this.context = executionContext.Value;

    var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(context.AppDirectory, "extra.json"));

  }
}
```

Note:
The above works using VS 2019 and Azure Functions 3.x

See:

- [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/issues/17#issuecomment-499086297)
- [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49597721/5770014)

Answer (score 0):

Based on current documentation, `ExecutionContext` is only available in the scope of a request when the function method is being invoked.

```
[FunctionName("Car")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
    HttpRequest req, 
    ExecutionContext context //<--
) {

    var path = context.FunctionAppDirectory;

    //...
}
```

It wont be available as yet in the constructor for injection when the function class is initialized.

Comment: Is there an alternative to ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory?