# Setting Azure Functions app's base directory wtih Azure Function app 2.x

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I need to set a Azure Functions app's base directory to the `azurewebjobsscriptroot` like below, but got exception

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath("%HOME%\site\wwwroot")   //error
    .AddJsonFile("Settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

> System.ArgumentException : The path must be absolute. Parameter name:
>   root    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String
>   root,ExclusionFilters filters)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.SetBasePath(IConfigurationBuilder
>   builder,String basePath)

Azure function 2.x

VS 2017

[ExecutionContext is null to non-function methods via IoC, alternative to ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093404/executioncontext-is-null-to-non-function-methods-via-ioc-alternative-to-executi)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsscriptroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to expand the path first before using it. That way the environment variable(s) embedded in the string can be replaced with the equivalent value of the variable. Resulting in a valid base path for the configuration.

```
var AzureWebJobsScriptRoot = "%HOME%\site\wwwroot";

var expandedRootPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(AzureWebJobsScriptRoot);

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(expandedRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("Settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

Reference [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables)