# Default Azure Function app base path D:\home\site\wwwroot Azure Function 2.x

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Currently, by default, Azure function base path is set to "D:\home\site\wwwroot". For example, when publishing, VS uploads app to this folder.

I need to read config file from this folder. We have problem of [ExecutionContext is null via dependency injection via constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093404/executioncontext-is-null-to-non-function-methods-via-ioc-alternative-to-executi)

Setting a new environment variable might cause issue if the path is changed in the future.

My question is that how can I use app base path that is reliable and stable, that works with DI via constructor.

Azure Function 2.x

VS 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an environment variable pointing to `home` directory. This would not change as many services including function app take dependency on it. Below is how function runtime fetches it in azure environment.

```
    string home = GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME");
    Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(home, "site", "wwwroot");
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide links?

Comment: As mentioned in the other post. This is how Azure app service and Azure functions determines this path. It is stable and consistent across all the hosting environments. The wiki link on the Azure functions documents this partially here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Configuration-Settings

Answer (score 2):

you can use function.json to have your configuration key pairs. 
for example:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

and in function.json you can do like this:
**"mykey": "myvalue"**

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.24",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
  {
      "direction":"in",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "runOnStartup": false,
      "name": "myTimer",
      "mykey": "myvalue"
  }
  ],
      "disabled": false,
      "scriptFile": "../bin/**.dll",
      "entryPoint": "**.Run"
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned on OP: Setting a new environment variable might cause issue if the path is changed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help others with latest Azure Function App version (v4). I have ApplicationInsights and it logs TRACE for me the ContentRootPath

```
Content root path: /home/site/wwwroot
```

[application_insights_log_traces.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm00e.png)

If you are using Azure Function isolated-process (worker). You are able to use `HostBuilderContext` to get base path easily. For example below:

```
var startup = new Startup();
var host = Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builer => { ... })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
            {
                builder.AddJsonFile(
                   Path.Combine(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "appsettings.json"),
                   false,
                   true
                );
            })
            .ConfigureServices(startup.ConfigureServices)
            .Build();
host.Run();
```

In the **your_azurefuncapp_project**.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>

        <!-- Should publish this file along to -->
        <None Update="appsettings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```