# How to get file path in Azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, file-io, azure-functions

I have an annoying problem that I initially thought I could solve in a few minutes, but it's starting to drive me nuts. I have an Azure Function app named 'Cars.' Within this Azure Function, there is a folder named 'Templates,' and inside this folder, there are several JSON files, such as CarsTemplateOne.json, CarsTemplateTwo.json, etc. What I want to do is read the contents of a specific file.
Initially, I attempted to use ExecutionContext, which is provided by the function itself

Schema:
-Cars
|-Templates
|-CarsTemplateOne.json
-Cars.cs

Example:

```
            try
            {
                string alertFilePath = Path.Combine(executionContext.FunctionAppDirectory, "Templates", $"{templateName}.json");
                if (File.Exists(alertFilePath))
                {
                    // Read the content of the file
                    return await File.ReadAllTextAsync(alertFilePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Template '{templateName}' does not exist at '{alertFilePath}'.");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error reading template file: {ex.Message}");
            }

            return null;
```

But when I deploy and run the function, this is the result:

> Template 'CarsTemplateOne' does not exist at '/home/site/wwwroot/Templates/CarsTemplateOne.json'.

I try to adjust the levels, but with no result

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, $"..{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}CarsTemplateOne.json"))
```

I noticed that when I run the function locally, this is the path that is generated:

```
"C:\\Users\\username\\source\\repos\\Vehicles\\Cars\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\Templates\\CarsTemplateOne.json"
```

However, there is no such folder in the 'bin' directory. This is why the local run is also broken. I am not sure what I messed up.

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597721/is-it-possible-to-read-file-from-same-folder-where-azure-function-exists) might be helpful.

Comment: Did you explicitly set in their properties "Copy to Output"?