# How to use local files in an Azure Function hosted on the Linux Consumption plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, stanford-nlp, ml.net

I have an event grid triggered function on Azure under the Linux Consumption plan. The code requires finding / loading some local model files. How do I get these files deployed to the Azure function and specify the path where the files are located? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: which Programming language you are using?

Comment: C# / Dotnet-isolated - 8.0

Comment: Check your project has a folder structure that includes your model file ProjectRoot
└── Models
    └── YourModelFile.dat
└── YourFunctionApp
    └── function1.cs
    └── function2.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy the local file to Azure you need to Add Item in your `.csproj` file.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="models\**\*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

> **Note :** here `models\**\*` is used to add all subdirectories and all its files

to get the path of the file use

```cs
var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
```

Thanks to @benspeth and @Louie Almeda
For reference check this [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/issues/17#issuecomment-498596856) and [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597721/is-it-possible-to-read-file-from-same-folder-where-azure-function-exists/49597847#49597847) respectively.

**#My Directory**

[image]

In `Isolated` model we need to define custom type for Event Properties as mentioned in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=python-v2,isolated-process,nodejs-v4,extensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp).

**`EventGridTrigger.cs`:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using Azure.Messaging;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class EventGridTrigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger<EventGridTrigger> _logger;

        public EventGridTrigger(ILogger<EventGridTrigger> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(EventGridTrigger))]
        public void Run([EventGridTrigger] MyEventType myEvent, FunctionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Event type: {myEvent.EventType}, Event subject: {myEvent.Subject}");

            try
            {
                var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
                Console.WriteLine(path);
                string modelContent = File.ReadAllText(path+"/models/model1.json");

                Console.Write($"Data of the file: {modelContent.ToString()}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error processing model1.json: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyEventType
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public string Topic { get; set; }

        public string EventType { get; set; }

        public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }

        public IDictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**`Csharp.csproj`:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.EventGrid" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="models\**\*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`model.json`:**

```json
{
  "model_name": "Model1",
  "description": "This is a sample model file.",
  "value":10,
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response with screenshots. My code was originally using `Environment.CurrentDirectory` which was returning the value /tmp/functions\standby\wwwroot. I now changed to `GetExecutingAssembly()` and it returns /home/site/wwwroot. This is also mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package

But my main issue ended up being that my model files were in a subfolder and subfolders do not appear to be created on the Linux host. I moved the files to the root of my local and now the files appear as "App Files".

Comment: I was also getting same error when using `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, locally it was working perfectly fine.